# How would you model a wealth distribution in R?

Tags: r, distributions

I am trying to model the wealth distribution of Germany with "random numbers".

Looking at diagrams, it seems to me that the wealth is distributed like Pareto.
Hence, I considered using the rpareto(n, location, shape = 1) function.
Would you generally agree with that?

Now, obviously "n" would be my sample size. But how do I find the settings for location and shape? Do I somehow have to use the Gini Coefficent or must I download some data and use the fitdistrplus package to find my parameters?

Note that im new to R and dont know much about statistics.
Thank you all :)

Comment: You'd need data from the relevant population to estimate Pareto parameters.

Comment: This paper looks promising: https://doi.org/10.6092/issn.1973-2201/1243 It contains parameter values for a non-Pareto model for multiple countries.

Comment: Why not sample from the observations themselves? You have some thousands or millions of values. Draw from them at random (with replacement).

Comment: Look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69438/fitting-data-in-a-generalized-pareto-distribution-and-parameter-estimation  and [the search ](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=estimat*+pareto+R+answers%3A1)